# using pandas apply() to create new columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
  Col1   Col2
0    A  code1
1    B  code1
2    C  code2
3    A  code1
```

I want to add a column to the DataFrame for each unique code value in Col 2 and put a 1 in the column that matches the code value and a 0 in all other newly-created columns.  In other words, I want a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
  Col1   Col2  Code1  Code2
0    A  code1      1      0
1    B  code1      1      0
2    C  code2      0      1
3    A  code1      1      0
```

The following code works for this small data sample:

```
def assign_code1(row):
    if row['Col2'] == 'code1' : return 1
    else :return 0

def assign_code2(row):
    if row['Col2'] == 'code2' : return 1
    else :return 0    

df['Code1'] = df.apply(assign_code1 ,axis=1)
df['Code2'] = df.apply(assign_code2 ,axis=1)
```

However, I really hate this code because:

- I have to know all the values in Col2;
- I have to write a separate function for each unique value in Col2; and
- I have read in other posts that using apply() to create new columns is frowned upon (though I didn't fully understand why - I have only been working with pandas for a couple of weeks).

I'd like to have code that obtains a list of all the unique values in Col2, creates a column for each, and correctly populates all the 1's and 0's in those columns.  Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: So just `pd.get_dummies(df.Col2)` to get your new columns.

Comment: Thank you!  I had not run across pd.get_dummies() before.  It does exactly what I want.